# Excel: SUMIF combined with LOOKUP for date between date range

Tags: excel

I have two sheets - 1) Reduction 2) Calendar.

A sampling of the data in Sheet #1 - Reduction:

```
     A          B           C           D 
1    Start      End         Resource    Reduction
2    1/4/2016   1/6/2016    Andrew      -8
3    3/11/2016  4/1/2016    Andrew      -2
4    1/5/2016   1/6/2016    Emily       -0.5
5    1/4/2016   1/7/2016    Andrew      -0.5
```

Format of Sheet #2 - Calendar:

```
     A          B           C           D           E           F
1    Resource   1/4/2016    1/5/2016    1/6/2016    1/7/2016    1/8/2016
2    Andrew                 
3    Maria                  
4    Emily
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is identify any reductions for the resource identified in Calendar A1:A4 and sum those reductions to identify a daily total reduction. I need to lookup the reductions and sum them from the Reduction sheet.

So for Cell Calendar C2 (Andrew for 1/5/16) I am looking at the Reductions sheet to find any of Andrew's reductions for the date of 1/5. Which should return then a reduction of -8.5 (rows 2 & 5 from the Reductions sheet = -8 + -.5).

I'm wondering if I can combine SUMIFS and LOOKUP to accomplish this or if there is a better way of going about it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMIFS():

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D:$D,Sheet1!$A:$A,"<="&B$1,Sheet1!$B:$B,">="&B$1,Sheet1!$C:$C,$A2)
```

[image]

Comment: That does not appear to be working - It's returning 0 for 1/4/16 which should return -8.5. I copied these mock tables and your provided function into a workbook to verify.

Comment: @mplutodh1 sooooo, I had the `>` and `<` backwards.  sorry.  see edit.

Comment: @mplutodh1 did this work for you?  If so then please mark as correct.  It is something only you can do.  Click on the green check mark by the answer.  It will close the question as answered.

Comment: it did work. Thank you! Good catch, I should have caught that as well. Thanks for the help.